# SettingWithCopyWarning when using custom transformer in SKLearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am consistently receiving a `SettingWithCopyWarning` in Python when transforming new data using a custom transformer I built in SKLearn. Basically I  need to create 3 new columns based off of one, and then drop that one column at the end of my transformer. The 'measurements' column is of the format "A x B x C mm" when I scrape the data, and I need to split that into an x, y and z column. I've tried putting `.loc`, using zip and a helper function, and both ways I receive the error.

What I am missing?

Helper function

```
def split_measures(x):
    return x.split(" ")[0], x.split(" ")[2], x.split(" ")[4]

class CategoricalTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    # Initialise function with parameters and data dictionaries for calculations
    def __init__(self, replacements = replacements):
        self._measurements = measurements
     
    # Do nothing, only return self
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    # Custom transformations
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        
        X["x"], X["y"], X['z'] = zip(*X["measurements"].map(split_measures))
        
        # Drop unneeded column
        X = X.drop(['measurements'], axis=1)
            
        # Return transformed dataframe
        return X
```

Comment: Its just a warning not an error so you can ignore that

Comment: Right that it was I have been doing - I guess if there's nothing wrong with my code then I will have to continue doing that. But just wanted to check if there's something off with what I am doing. Thanks!